# How to target tag in SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following

```
<body>
  <div class="app" theme="light">
    <div class="container">¨
      <div class="wrapper">
        <p class="text">something></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

How do I target a specific div in SASS even if it's a few divs up. I mean something like this.

```
p
  color: red
  [theme="dark"] &
    color: green
```

I mean change color based on light/dark theme. Plenty of stuff is far below this "app" div. In SASS, I think it was somehow possible to target specify parent div (even though it is behind a large number of tags), but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

CSS only cascades down, but you can use:

```
.app 
  p
    color: red
  &[theme="dark"]
  p
    color: green
```

This way you say that all `p` elements in `div.app` should have the color red, but if `div.app` also has the `theme` attribute with the value of `dark`, then the color for all `p` should be green.

Comment: I think cascading up is possible in SASS, but I don't remember how it was anymore

Answer (score 1):

it would be :

```
div 
  color: red    
  &[theme="light"]
    color: green
```

wich is compiled this way :

```
div {
  color: red;
}
div[theme="light"] {
  color: green;
}
```

See what it does with plain CSS.

```css
div {
  color: red;
}
div[theme="light"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
  <div class="app" theme="light">
    <div class="container">¨
      <div class="wrapper">
        <p class="text">something</p>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

but it still renders red , even in plain CSS, you need obviously to increase CSS specifity to see it work.

It could be here :

```
div 
  color: red    
  &[theme="light"] div
    color: green
```

plain CSS demo

```css
div {
  color: red;
}
div[theme="light"] div {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
  <div class="app" theme="light">
    <div class="container">¨
      <div class="wrapper">
        <p class="text">something</p>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It might not answer your trouble, but t least , you should know how it works .